What might be the reason for slow SFTP connections to local virtual machine?
I have an Ubuntu 22.04 server on VMWare Workstation on my local development machine (Windows 10) for development purposes. It runs Apache/MySQL and has sufficient allocated memory and CPU.
When connecting to that server over HTTP and SFTP from same (host) machine, it has latency for several seconds. I am using Chrome as browser and PHPStorm built-in upload feature and Filezilla for SFTP transfers. On Chrome it was waiting to load page and images, same on SFTP uploads too.
I tried to diagnose the problem but connections (HTTP/SFTP) from other computers on same network didn't have that latency, also Edge/Firefox didn't have that latency on host computer too. And I re-installed Chrome again on host computer, it also solved problem with HTTP connections and now loads instantly. But SFTP connections' latency still persists. Remote computers transferring files over SFTP instantly too.
I checked DNS as well for HTTP but for SFTP I'm connecting over IP (VM using bridged mode with it's static IP).
What might be the reason for this problem, Thanks in advance for any help/ideas.
In addition to above, I found SFTP upload time increases with each try and then fails.
Here are the logs:
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload
[25.07.2024 02:51] Upload file 'C:\projectfiles\testproject\resources\sass\app.scss' to '/var/www/testproject/resources/sass/app.scss'
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload completed in 330 ms: 1 file transferred (74.6 kbit/s)
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload
[25.07.2024 02:51] Upload file 'C:\projectfiles\testproject\resources\sass\app.scss' to '/var/www/testproject/resources/sass/app.scss'
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload completed in 2 sec, 220 ms: 1 file transferred (11 kbit/s)
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload
[25.07.2024 02:51] Upload file 'C:\projectfiles\testproject\resources\sass\app.scss' to '/var/www/testproject/resources/sass/app.scss'
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload completed in 4 sec, 370 ms: 1 file transferred (5.6 kbit/s)
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload
[25.07.2024 02:51] Upload file 'C:\projectfiles\testproject\resources\sass\app.scss' to '/var/www/testproject/resources/sass/app.scss'
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload completed in 5 sec, 124 ms: 1 file transferred (4.7 kbit/s)
[25.07.2024 02:51] Automatic upload
[25.07.2024 02:51] Upload file 'C:\projectfiles\testproject\resources\sass\app.scss' to '/var/www/testproject/resources/sass/app.scss'
[25.07.2024 02:52] Failed to transfer file 'C:\projectfiles\testproject\resources\sass\app.scss'. Could not close the output stream for file "sftp://192.168.1.230/var/www/testproject/resources/sass/app.scss".
[25.07.2024 02:52] Automatic upload completed in 34 sec, 39 ms: 1 item failed


when you say latency, you are saying that the transfer takes a few seconds to start, but once started moves at an acceptable speed? how many cores does your VM have compared to the host? has the server been idle before you test in some cases but not others?

@FrankThomas both -sometimes- takes a few seconds to start and also takes some time to transfer, even for a 20 KB .css file. But happens on host machine to VM only. From remote laptop to VM, it works perfectly. Server has been idle, also I tried remote/local transfers on exactly same time too. Server has 2 processors (1 core per processor), 4 GB memory on 6 core AMD Ryzen 5 3600 CPU with 16 GB memory.
I was using same configuration for a long time and that problem started a short while ago and couldn't find what affected.

My first guess would be the VMware layer. if the VM is largely idle, it may take a few seconds to become active. is the host starved for CPU or RAM? how active is the disk the vm's virtual disks are on?

@FrankThomas when mentioning "idle", i didn't mean idle for a long time, just not running anything resource hungry.  Host or server has sufficient free CPU/memory. Also that happens only for host to guest VM connections, not for other client on same network, so I don't think it's related to VM or resources. For HTTP, reinstalling Chrome solved the problem. Weird situation.

You say you checked the DNS - how did you do it - to me this seems very much like it could be a DNS issue.

@davidgo now it happens on IP connection only, there is no DNS involvement. I found it  seems happening when there is SSH (putty) connection to server meanwhile uploading with SFTP. Something like "maximum connection reached" issue but I have one connection  with Putty and max 5 connections with PhpStorm. CPU/memory on server is still fine at that moment.

are you logging out of the session when you are done with your upload?

Could it be an MTU or MSS (ethernet packet size related) issue? If it's happening with scp but not so much ssh  interactive sessions, catting a longish file and seeing if it freezes could point to this.
